# Java read XML and put textnodes into an array of strings?

Tags: java, xml

I apologize if this question has been asked somewhere, I've been searching on google for over an hour and can't seem to figure out how to do this.

I've created a config file for an application I'm making which is stored in XML and I've gotten the application to successfully create the XML file if it doesn't exist using DOM,

(code,in case it's needed)

```
    public static void newConfig() {
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root element
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("settings");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // address element
        Element address = doc.createElement("address");
        address.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("127.0.0.1"));
        rootElement.appendChild(address);

        // port element
        Element port = doc.createElement("port");
        port.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("3306"));
        rootElement.appendChild(port);

        // user element
        Element user = doc.createElement("user");
        user.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("user"));
        rootElement.appendChild(address);

        // password element
        Element pass = doc.createElement("pass");
        pass.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("password"));
        rootElement.appendChild(pass);

        // database element
        Element datab = doc.createElement("database");
        datab.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("A1"));
        rootElement.appendChild(datab);

        // write the content to XML
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("config.xml"));
        transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
        }

        }
```

which creates this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<settings>
<port>3306</port>
<address>127.0.0.1</address>
<pass>password</pass>
<database>A1</database>
</settings>
```

how would I go about retrieving those textnodes as an array of strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
    NodeList nodes = docBuilder.parse(new File("1.xml")).getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
    String[] a = new String[4];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
        Node n = nodes.item(i);
        if (n instanceof Element) {
            a[j++] = n.getTextContent().trim();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, this worked perfectly thanks :)